# How to install and run babeltrace2 on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I followed the [instruction](https://babeltrace.org/docs/v2.0/python/bt2/installation.html#build-and-install-from-source) to build and install the babeltrace2 python3 bindings.

Then I got the `babeltrace2` binary at: `/usr/local/bin/babeltrace2`

But when I tried to run it, it reports below error:

> babeltrace2: error while loading shared libraries:
> libbabeltrace2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory

I used `apt-file search libbabeltrace2` to find the package that contains this lib.
Unfortunately there's no result.

Then I tried `apt-file search libbabeltrace`. It returns a lot of results but they are all for `libbabeltrace1`.

So how can I install and run the `babeltrace2` on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: *Linux distributions typically provide the Babeltrace 2 Python bindings as the python3-bt2 package.*

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks but I did try `apt search python3-bt2` and there's no result.

Comment: `python3-bt2`is available in 22.04 repositories, don't know (and can't test) about 20.04.

Comment: Thanks, let me try to add the 22.04 repo. Not sure if it's safe...

Comment: Generally, when building from source I'd expect e.g. (here) `libbabeltrace2.so.0` to appear in the build tree and be installed by `make install` - might it be that part of the build or install failed for you?  **NOTED: Yet another package that has no INTRODUCTION - if you do not know what this package is meant to do, then you will remain out in the dark.**

Comment: @Hannu Yeah it seems the dark has taken me... I make build and make install, now my Ubuntu failed to boot...

Answer (score 2):

A
[package search for babeltrace](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=babeltrace)
shows that `babeltrace` is available, but that `babeltrace2`
is only available from version 21.10 and onward.

It is unsafe to update packages outside of their context.
You should rather upgrade Ubuntu itself, or compile the package
from source.